# Counting Customers in different ways - Do I need a SubQuery?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Imagine a situation where a customer is given a free gift if they open an account. Some ‘customers’ open an account to get the free gift, but never add any money to their account. Other ‘customers’ open accounts, get the free gift and also fund their accounts by adding money to it.

I need to compare the funded accounts to the overall count of all customers.

Things at first appeared quite easy …

```
 SELECT Audits.AuditDate, Count(Audits.NickName) AS AllAccounts
 FROM Audits
 Group By Audits.AuditDate
```

This obviously gives me the count of all accounts on a daily basis.

To get the ‘Funded’ count, I do …

```
 SELECT Audits.AuditDate, Count(Audits.NickName) AS Funded
 FROM Audits 
 WHERE Audits.CurrGBP > 0
 GROUP BY Audits.AuditDate;
```

This time I get the count of the ‘Funded’ accounts.

Now, this is where I get stuck … I want both counts from the same query so my results would be like this …

```
AuditDate (DD/MM/YYYY)      AllAccounts Funded
01/01/2012                  50          45
02/01/2012                  60          50
03/01/2012                  70          55
```

Something is telling me I need to use a Sub Query, but after googling a few pages. Sub Queries are baffling to me.

May I ask for some help please ? Can you show me how to write a Sub Query to give me the results I need.

Regards,
John.

PS  - My Audits table has the following fields, Audit_ID, Audit_Date, NickName, CurrGBP and I am using MS Access 2010.

Comment: +1 for a very good write-up explaining and providing good detail.  A "Well thought out and explained question"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cant remember if access supports case; or if IIF is the way to go... but something like...

A sub query isn't really needed, you can get the results in one query, just limit what you count when using a case or IIF.

```
Select A.AuditDate,
count (A.NickName) as AllAccounts,
sum(CASE when A.CurrGBP > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Funded
FROM Audits A
GROUP BY A.AuditDate
```

if IIF

```
Select A.AuditDate,
count (A.NickName) as AllAccounts,
sum(IIF(A.CurrGBP >0,1,0)) as Funded
FROM Audits A
GROUP BY A.AuditDate
```

EDIT, was missing some commas in selects.

Comment: Thank you. The CASE example doesn't work, but the IIF does. I need to investigate this more as I simplified my table fields for the question ... in reality I have another 2 fields (CurrUSD and CurrEUR) that I need to include in your SUM(), but this has certainly helped.

Comment: +1, Johnny it may also be worth looking at the 'Crosstab Queries' feature; especially if you are working with several columns, these can be built through the query designer and are the same concept as an Excel Pivot Table.

Comment: @Johnny: If you want to count accounts that are funded in *any* supported currency, just extend the `IIF` condition like this: `IIF( CurrGBP > 0 OR CurrUSD > 0 OR ...)`. If your main goal is to count accounts that are just not empty, that should suffice, I think.

Comment: @ xQBert - Getting closer to what I need with the IIF statement. This seems to pretty much give me everything I need ... Select A.AuditDate, count (A.NickName) as AllAccounts,
sum(IIF(A.CurrGBP > 0, 1, IIF(A.CurrUSD > 0, 1, IIF(A.CurrEUR > 0, 1, 0)))) as Funded
FROM Audits A
GROUP BY A.AuditDate

Comment: @Andriy M - Brilliant - much simpler and more elegant than my nested IIF. Thanks.

Comment: @Johnny sorry, life got in the way.  Do you still need assistance here or has the IIF and Andriy M's assistance given you all you needed?

Comment: @xQbert - Yes, you have pretty much answered what I needed to know and Andriy M helped me expand things to finish things ...
SUM(IIF(A.CurrGBP > 0 OR A.CurrUSD > 0 OR A.CurrEur > 0, 1, 0) as Funded. I think I do need to get to grips with SubQueries, I get the feeling they are quite powerful and will give me more info. Rather than ask another question here I thought it would be best to create a new question.

Comment: @johnny great to hear.  subqueries correlated, as in Johntotetwoo's response, or otherwise (like in a where clause or select) are very powerful. Have to be careful though sometimes they do impact performance.  You may want to take a moment and look at the Stack [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) about asking and getting responses to questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT  AuditA.AuditDate, 
        Count(AuditA.AllAcounts) as AllAccount,
        iTable.iCount
FROM Audits as AuditA
       INNER JOIN 
           (SELECT AuditB.Audit_ID, COUNT(AuditB.Audit_ID) as iCount
            FROM Audit as AuditB
            WHERE AuditB.CurrGBP > 0) as iTable
       ON AuditA.Audit_ID = iTable.Audit_ID
```

Comment: Thank you johntotetwoo, I haven't tried your solution yet but will give it a go. It's quite interesting what you have done ie joined the table to itself, I hadn't realised you could do that.